# Como converter dia do ano para data (sem timestamp) [PostgreSQL]?

Tags: postgresql, data

*Tenho o valor `2016001` simbolizando o primeiro dia do ano de 2016, como faço para pegar por exemplo o `ANO/MES` de `2016263`?*

---

### Exemplo:

```
ENTRADA: $data = '2016001'
SAÍDA: $anomes = '2016-01'
```

---

*Se tivesse como fazer o inverso desse `SQL`:*

> SELECT extract(DOY FROM TIMESTAMP '2016-12-31 23:59:59') AS dia;
>
> SAIDA: 366
>
> ---

### EDITADO:

*Assim eu extraio somente o número do dia do ano:*

> SELECT SUBSTRING(TO_CHAR(2016263, '9999999') FROM 6 FOR 3)
>
> SAIDA: 263
>
> Ou da maneira mais fácil:
>
> SELECT RIGHT(2016263::VARCHAR, 3);
>
> SAIDA: 263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser utilizada uma combinação das funções `to_date` e `to_char`.

A função `to_date` irá converter o varchar que você possui (`2016263`) em um date.

A função `to_char` irá converter essa data para o formato ano/mês que você precisa retornar (`2016/09`).

```
select to_char(to_date(cast(2016263 as varchar),'yyyyDDD'),'yyyy/mm');

 to_char 
---------
 2016/09
(1 registro)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: No meu caso ele `2016263` é um inteiro, então vou modificar sua resposta colocando um `CAST` para ficar correta! Obrigado pela colaboração!

Comment: Blz @MarcosHenzel

Comment: Não deixaram eu melhorar a tua resposta para ficar correta, rejeitaram as modificações, mas tudo bem, alguns dados ficarão errados aí na resposta, referente aos dados que eu passei na pergunta.

Comment: Sem problemas, editei o comando SQL